# Firestore limit

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, google-cloud-firestore

Firestore offers 50000 documents read operations as part of its free bundle.

However, in my application, the client is fetching a collection containing price data. The price data is created over time. Hence, starting from a specific timestamp, the client can read up to 1000 documents. Each document represents one timestamp with the price information.
This is means that if the client refreshes his/her web browser 50 times, it will exhaust my quota immediately. And that is just for a single client.
That is what happened. And got this error:

> Error: 8 RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: Quota exceeded

The price data are static. Once they have been written, it is not supposed to change.
Is there a solution for this issue or I should consider other database other than Firestore?

Comment: Answer below. Beyond that, it's impossible to say whether you've actually ready that number without seeing the [minimal code with which we can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also definitely consider using the Firebase Realtime Database, which has a different pricing model that seems to allow developers to get further in their experiments before hitting quotas.

Answer (score 5):

The error message indicates that you've exhausted the quota that is available. On the free plan the quota is 50,000 document reads per day, so you've read that number of documents already.

Possible solutions:

- Upgrade to a paid plan, which has a much higher quota.
- Wait until tomorrow to continue, since the quota resets every day.
- Try in another free project, since each project has its own quota.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a dataset that will never-ever (or rarely) change, why not write it as JSON object in the app itself. You could make it a separate .js file and then import for reading to make your table.

Alternatively - is there a reason your users would ever navigate through all 1,000 records. You can simulate a full table even with limiting to calls to say 10 or so and then paginate to get more results if needed.